# XMLHttpRequestUpload loadend event fires immediately regardless of actual upload process in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, upload, xmlhttprequest

When I call this function in my react app ( awaiting it in a try...catch block ) the onloadend and onprogress events are fired immediately although the actual uploading process takes some time ( I monitor it in network tab) and also the progress event is fired immediately showing 100% loaded.

```js
const uploadData = (method, url, data) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', data )
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url);
      xhr.upload.onprogress = (e) => console.log(`Uploaded:${e.loaded} of ${e.total}`);
      xhr.upload.onloadend = (e) => console.log('finished');
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        xhr.onload = () => {
          if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
            resolve(xhr.response);
          } else {
            reject({
              status: xhr.status,
              statusText: xhr.statusText,
            });
          }
        };
        xhr.onerror = () => {
          reject({
            status: xhr.status,
            statusText: xhr.statusText,
          });
        };
        xhr.send(formData)
      });
    };
```

I've tried to use big files to make a gradual progress but no difference.
I've also tried running built app on a remote server sending to another remote endpoint but no difference.
btw onload works fine and resolves when request is successful

Comment: MDN docs make this note for attaching listeners to the upload object: *The spec also seems to indicate that event listeners should be attached after open(). However, browsers are buggy on this matter, and often need the listeners to be registered before open() to work.* - see if moving the `.open` after attaching the listeners helps. Also, check in multiple browsers, you may find doing this fixes the issue for your current browser, but breaks other browsers

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried that but no difference I also tried moving them into the promise constructor but still the same.

Comment: which browser(s)?

Comment: Edge and chrome

Comment: So, only one browser

Comment: I used BrowserStack to test safari and Firefox and same results.I think the problem is related to the react and virtual dom somehow, looks like when the component is mounted xhr fires onloadend and 100% progress events.

Comment: I can't see why react would interfere with XMLHttpRequest functionality .... what if you use `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", fn);` instead of `xhr.upload.onprogress = fn;`

Comment: That also didn't work. Here's a sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/xhr-upload-hhvtht

Comment: works fine for me, progresses nicely - how big a file are you trying? how fast is your internet upstream?

Comment: My upload bandwidth is quite low. when I use a large file I can see the progress but it doesn't correspond to the actual data transfer to server it looks like the progress of file loading into buffer or ram or sth. I guess there is a problem with my system than. thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing on another system, I have determined that the issue stems from the Kaspersky Anti-virus application. The web anti-virus component of the application, in conjunction with the enabled "Inject script into web traffic to interact with web pages" option, is causing the premature triggering of progress and loadend events. I believe that the anti-virus application proxies the data during traffic processing, causing xhr requests to fire these events when data is loaded onto the proxy server rather than the actual server.